# Ext-JS Using View Form Data in Controller as Ajax Request Param

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, controller

I am pretty new to Ext-JS.

I have a form in view which contains a table layout with two columns. One column contains another table layout with three text fields, a button and a grid panel.

I have a controller which has a listener for button(inner table layout), I am using a Ajax Request and need to pass values of three text fields as Params. I tried several ways but cannot pass param values.

I almost researched a day and found different ways like using Ext.getCmp method but none of them really worked.

From my past web experience, I am thought we need to access form and its elements from its id or name, but it didn't worked.

Can someone point me to some good resource to understand Ext-Js Architecture and Forms.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it, Patience Wins! .

```
var win = btn.up('window'),
form = win.down('form');
form.getForm().findField('NamePropertyValue').getSubmitValue()
```

The above code worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ExtJS 4.0 the following link:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/xml-form.html

provides a good example with source showing how to load and save data through AJAX requests and an Ext.form.Panel component. Other form examples can be found at this link:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/#sample-13

These example links are both from Sencha's website so they both should contain examples implementing best ExtJS practices.